# Travel to Spain with Norway residence permit

Tags: schengen, spain

I am a student from Kosovo studying in Norway, and I have a residence permit. I want to know if I can travel to Spain for vacation.

Comment: Also "...You do not need to apply for a Schengen visa if you have a category "D" visa from any of the member states. Category "D" visas include..." at http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/51048/schengen-visa-application-tips-for-preparing

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can.  A residence permit or national long-stay visa for a Schengen country allows the bearer to spend up to 90 days in any 180-day period in other Schengen countries.

This isn't entirely obvious from the [Schengen Borders Code](http://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=CELEX:02006R0562-20131126), but it does say this:

> 1. For intended stays on the territory of the Member States of a duration of no more than 90 days in any 180-day period, which entails considering the 180-day period preceding each day of stay, the entry conditions for third-country nationals shall be the following:
>
> [...]
>
> (b) they are in possession of a valid visa, if required pursuant to Council Regulation (EC) No 539/2001 of 15 March 2001 listing the third countries whose nationals must be in possession of visas when crossing the external borders and those whose nationals are exempt from that requirement, *except where they hold a valid residence permit or a valid long-stay visa;*

Emphasis added.  This means that your residence permit exempts you from the requirement to hold a visa.

Comment: Is there a way you can reconcile this answer with the previous answer http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/36541/help-with-student-visa-and-tourist-visa/36559#36559 which provides the same citation, information?  Do we need two answers citing the same paragraph in the Borders Code?

Comment: @GayotFow the question you linked to is somewhat different. That question is about time; this one is about space. The fact that the answer comes from the same source seems incidental.